# Getting undefined after parsing the data in node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to upload an image to S3 from a AWS lambda function. For this I have followed this tutorial - [link](https://medium.com/think-serverless/image-upload-and-retrieval-from-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda-b4c2961e8d1). I have created an post API using API Gateway and written nodejs code in lambda to post an image to S3. But I am getting below error from API Gateway while trying to test the API.

```
"errorType": "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]",
"errorMessage": "The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined",
"code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE",
"stack": [
    "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined",
    "    at Function.from (buffer.js:207:11)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:17:32)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:63:25)",
    "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
```

My lambda code looks like below:-

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//*/ get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {


     let encodedImage =JSON.parse(event.body).user_avatar;
     let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');
     var filePath = "avatars/" + event.queryStringParameters.username + ".jpg"
     var params = {
       "Body": decodedImage,
       "Bucket": "find-my-mate-hasangi",
       "Key": filePath  
    };
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
       if(err) {
           callback(err, null);
       } else {
           let response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "my_header": "my_value"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(data),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
           callback(null, response);
    }
    });

};
```

I am getting error in below line:-

```
 let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');
```

I am passing below body from API Gateway:-

```
{
  "body": {
    "user_avatar": "asas"
  }
}
```

- Update: I have tried some debugging after suggestions in comments

> ```
> console.log( event.body);         // Output: { "body": { "user_avatar": "Hi There!" } }
> console.log( JSON.parse(event.body)); // Output: { body: { user_avatar: 'Hi There' } } 
> console.log( event.body.user_avatar);               // Output: undefined
> console.log( JSON.parse(event.body).user_avatar);   // Output: undefined
> ```

The code is written in Node JS v6.10 which is not available in lambda anymore. So I am using Node JS v10.x. Can it be the reason for the error? Anyone know how to resolve the error.

Comment: Try to console.log event.body. It will help you understand the structure and the type of the body

Comment: @dimagolovin thanks for the reply. I have tried adding console.log and getting below response { "body": { "user_avatar": "Hi There!" } }

Comment: Is the user_avatar actually in the event body?

Comment: Yes user_avatar is in body. console.log(JSON.parse(event.body).user_avatar) is returning "undefined".

Comment: try let encodedImage = event.body.user_avatar

Comment: console.log( event.body.user_avatar);  and
 console.log( JSON.parse(event.body).user_avatar);   
      
Both the above lines are displaying "undefined".

Comment: @dimagolovin I have added some more debugging in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data that you pass lives in `event.body`. Since you are passing object that also starts from `body`, you should access it like this:

```
JSON.parse(event.body).body.user_avatar
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't notice it. It worked now. Thanks a lot.